# Reading elements for a vector until EOL

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a novice to programming completely. I'm trying to teach myself C++. I want to write code to create two vectors and read their elements from input.

```
vector<int> v1, v2;
/*Reading vector values*/
cout << "Enter the elements of 1st vector" << endl;
int ele;
while (cin >> ele)
    v1.push_back(ele);
cout << "enter the elements of 2nd vector" << endl;
while (cin >> ele)
    v2.push_back(ele);
```

Though it basically does what I coded it for, I want to have some improvements.

1. When I input elements into a vector, I would like <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to mean that I'm done entering the vector, while a <kbd>space</kbd> key says I'm entering the next element.
2. How can I write a loop for vector 1 and vector 2, as the code for entering elements is the same for both the vectors? (I want to write a loop for reading the two vectors.)

Comment: Although [it's too late to edit now that you've received an answer](/help/someone-answers), it's worth noting for the future that you'll receive better reviews if you post code that's more complete.  For example, I recommend that you show the necessary `#include` lines, and the `using std::vector;` and similar that we must assume.  It's not mandatory, but it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest solution is to read the input line and parse it. You are also correct it is a good idea to write a function for reading a vector.

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> read_vector()
{
    std::string line = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::vector<int> v;

    int x = 0;
    while (iss >> x)
        v.push_back(x);

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the elements of 1st vector\n";
    std::vector<int> v1 = read_vector();

    std::cout << "Enter the elements of 2nd vector\n";
    std::vector<int> v2 = read_vector();

    std::cout << "v1 = { ";
    for (auto e : v1)
        std::cout << e << " ";

    std::cout << "}\nv2 = { ";
    for (auto e : v2)
        std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << "}";
}
```

The functionality of reading a vector is now found from `read_vector`; quite obviously, it reads the input string (until the delimiter, which is by default an end of the line), and reads space-separated integers, pushes them to the vector, and returns it.

Comment: @AccidentalGenius you may want to have a look at [this section in the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Great! But a question - I don

Comment: @CutePoison Your comment was cut short. Did you want to ask something?